# Problem with Downloading ownCloud on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, owncloud

So I am getting this error that keeps popping up when I try and open ownCloud and this is what I receive

```
PHP module mb multibyte not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

PHP modules have been installed, but they are still listed as missing?
Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server.
```

I have been trying and I will keep trying to figure out the problem but I think it has to do with this package.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install php3-dom  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php3-dom
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Don't know what this has to do with python, but why are you trying to install it for php3? I don't think up-to-date guides use php3

Comment: And why don't you think it has to do with "module mb multibyte not installed" since that is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the instructions from [makeusof.com](https://www.makeuseof.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/)? It seems that the commands are dated, like the older `php7.3` rather than `php7.4`.

Run this command from the [official documentation](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.10/admin_manual/installation/quick_guides/ubuntu_20_04.html#install-the-required-packages):

```
sudo apt install -y \
  apache2 libapache2-mod-php \
  mariadb-server openssl redis-server wget php-imagick \
  php-common php-curl php-gd php-gmp php-bcmath php-imap \
  php-intl php-json php-mbstring php-mysql php-ssh2 php-xml \
  php-zip php-apcu php-redis php-ldap php-phpseclib
```

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't be `php3-dom`. Maybe `php5.3-dom`, `php5-dom` or `php7.3-dom`. You have wrong command.